# Recursive regex not matching template blocks

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to understand more about regex and in this case the recursion you can do in a regular expression.

I'm trying to match a nested block of `{foreach $VAR} ... {/foreach}`. But for some reason my regex isn't matching and i don't understand why.

I was hoping anyone here could shed some light on it. I'm **not** interested in a quick regex fix. But really more as why my regex isn't doing what i expect. What exactly is happening?

This is the code i have:

```
<?php
$str = 'start of text
{foreach $ABC}
  in 1st loop
  {foreach $XYZ}
    in 2nd loop
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
some other stuff';

if ( preg_match ( '#{foreach \$.*?}((?!foreach)|(?R))*{/foreach}#', $str, $matches ) )
{
    print_r($matches);
}
else
{
    echo 'No match';
}
```

Here is the breakdown of my regex as how i think it's wokring:

```
{foreach \$     #match literally "{foreach $"
.*?}            #followed by any character ending with a '}'
(               # start a group
  (?!foreach)   # match any character, aslong as it's not the sequence 'foreach'
  |             # otherwise
  (?R)          # do a recursion
)               # end of group
*               # match 0 or more times with a backtrace...
{/foreach}      # ...backtracing until you find the last {/foreach}
```

That's how i think the regex works. But obviously that is not the case. So my question is, where am i wrong in my explanation?

You can play around with this code here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/508V9w

---

Just to clarify.

I'm trying to get the contents of each `foreach` block. So in my case:

```
arr[0] => in 1st loop
      {foreach $XYZ}
        in 2nd loop
      {/foreach}
arr[1] => in 2nd loop
```

OR -

```
arr[0] => {foreach $ABC}
      in 1st loop
      {foreach $XYZ}
        in 2nd loop
      {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
arr[1] => {foreach $XYZ}
        in 2nd loop
      {/foreach}
```

Either will do fine.

Comment: Does that pattern compile? `{` and `}` are special characters in regex land.

Comment: @KennethK. Yes it seems to compile fine. I also see no difference when i escape them. But maybe it's better for me to that do that anyway from now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `.` does match *anything but* newlines per default. To have it match newlines as well, you have to set the modifier `s`.

And secondly, you are using assertions here: `((?!foreach)|(?R))*`, but no actual characters to match. You need at least a dot before the `*` quantifier or something.

`#{foreach \$.*?}((?!foreach)|(?R)).*{/foreach}#s` gives the following result with your test text:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {foreach $ABC}
  in 1st loop
  {foreach $XYZ}
    in 2nd loop
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
    [1] => 
)
```

Comment: I forgot to add the `s` modifier in my post. But as you can see it's there in the *codepad* page. By adding a `.` before the asteriks it indeed gives me the result that you show. But how come it isn't capturing the inner `{foreach $XYZ}`? I was hoping this regex was able to do that. Also not sure where the empty match comes from `[1]`, any ideas?

Comment: There is no capturing, because you did not set appropriate capturing parentheses around the subpattern.